# decision tree Python with exceptions 2.7

Tags: if-statement, python-2.7

I'm writing a script which calculates the date of Easter for years 1900 - 2099.
The thing is that for 4 certain years (1954, 1981, 2049, and 2076) the formula differs a little bet (namely, the date is off 7 days).

```
def main():
    print "Computes the date of Easter for years 1900-2099.\n"

    year = input("The year: ")

    if year >= 1900 and year <= 2099:
        if year != 2049 != 2076 !=1981 != 1954:
            a = year%19
            b = year%4 
            c = year%7
            d = (19*a+24)%30
            e = (2*b+4*c+6*d+5)%7
            date = 22 + d + e     # March 22 is the starting date
            if date <= 31:
                print "The date of Easter is March", date
            else:
                print "The date of Easter is April", date - 31
        else: 
            if date <= 31:
                print "The date of Easter is March", date - 7 
            else:
                print "The date of Easter is April", date - 31 - 7
    else:
        print "The year is out of range."   


main()
```

Exerything is working well but the 4 years computation.

I'm getting the:
`if date <= 31:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'date' referenced before assignment` whenever I'm entering any of the 4 years as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot chain a expression like that; chain the tests using `and` operators or use a `not in` expression instead:

```
# and operators
if year != 2049 and year != 2076 and year != 1981 and year != 1954:

# not in expression
if year not in (2049, 2076, 1981, 1954):
```

The expression `year != 2049 != 2076 !=1981 != 1954` means something different, it is interpreted as `(((year != 2049) != 2076) !=1981) != 1954` instead; the first test is either `True` or `False`, and neither of those two values will ever be equal to any of the other numbers and that branch will *always* evaluate to `False`.

You will still get the `UnboundLocalError` for `date` though, since your `else` branch refers to `date` but it is never set in that branch. When the `else` branch executes, all Python sees is:

```
def main():
    print "Computes the date of Easter for years 1900-2099.\n"

    year = input("The year: ")

    if year >= 1900 and year <= 2099:
        if False:    
            # skipped
        else: 
            if date <= 31:
                print "The date of Easter is March", date - 7 
            else:
                print "The date of Easter is April", date - 31 - 7
```

and `date` is never assigned a value in that case. You need to calculate `date` separately in that branch still, *or* move the calculation of the `date` value out of the `if` statement altogether; I am not familiar with the calculation of Easter so I don't know what you need to do in this case.

Comment: If I'm reading the code right, all that needs to be done is to move the the `a = ` to `date =` lines one level to the left, and then move the `if year not in` line to below the `date = ` line.

Comment: you really casted light on the LocalError with the last code @Martijn for which I'm very grateful once again.

Comment: you're reading the code perfectly @DSM , it worked!!! thanks.  I owe you guys, big time.